# Return dummy info from laravel relationship

Tags: laravel

In laravel we specify foreign keys this way

```
public function creator() {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'creator_id', 'id');
}
```

Is there some way to return dummy user ('system') when creator_id is null?

Reason: to display it in template.

For example:

If creator_id = 10 `=>` creator = {id: 1, name: 'John'}

If creator_id = null `=>` creator = {id: 0, name: 'system'}

Comment: Your reference table won't enter your record if there is no reated user in your user table

Comment: I need this only to display in template info that `creator` is `system user`, not real user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your template :

```
{{ (model->creator) ? model->creator->name : 'system' }}
```

**model** will replace with your variable name.

Comment: May be there is a better way using getAttribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy user with id = 0 and name = 'System'.

Give the creator_id a default value of 0 in the migration